# asp.net MVC action link need to have the registered on the actual word

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

got this actionlink:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Corian&reg; Worktops", "Index", "Corian")%>
```

the word corian has to carry the registered symbol or the word can not be used, but it seems to process, i know i could just write this as a normal href but it kinda defeats the object if there is another solution.

has any tried and successfully caried something like this out?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works normally

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("RegistededMark®", "Action")%>
```

Use the normal ® symbol but make sure the font in HTML displays it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why but having static text in the views gives me the chills. I would rather suggest that you use a resource provider to fill in your link text. That way you will not be bothered by the html encoding stuff.